# is it OK to retain a variable passed by value in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pass-by-reference, retain

is it OK to retain a variable passed by value in objective-c?

That is say:

- I have controller 1 I have a variable that I pass to controller 2
- it's effectively passed by reference and I can use this when the use clicks on the controller 2 UINavigationController backbutton, in that the value will be modified in controller 1
- in controller 2 I have setup a ivar per the code below

Question - So is it OK for this controller 2 variable to be set using "Retain", and also have it "released" and set to nil in the "dealloc" method?  that is it won't affect the object for controller 1?  What happens for example if controller 2 is deallocated and the "release" and "=nil" is hit, will this affect the object as it's still used by controller 1.

Controller 2 Code extract

```
@interface SelectorController : UITableViewController {
    Config *_returnObject;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) Config *returnObject;
@end


// implementation
@synthesize config;  
- (void)dealloc
{
    [config release];               config = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: In your implementation, you talk about something called `config`.  In the interface you are using `returnObject`

Comment: Parameters are always passed by value in C and Objective C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retaining and releasing the variable in controller 2 is more than OK, it's how you should do it. :)

Setting the variable to `nil` in the controller 2, will only set the variable to nil, not the stuff the variable points to, so your object will still be there for the variable in controller 1 to work with.

Comment: Though generally there's no need to nil the variable in dealloc.  The variable will never be referenced again, short of a bug.

Comment: I'd go further than that - I'd never set it to nil in dealloc so if there is a bug, you will see it as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends, its ok for you to retain the variable in View Controller 2. Because each controller will be responsible for theirs variables. If instead, you assign your variable, even if you are using the variable in the second controller, it will be the first controller the responsible.